# Convert Office 2007-2012 docs to pdf and image in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ms-office

We have developed an app that can import DOC/XLS files as images using LibreOffice. However, for PCs where Office is already installed, we would like to be able to use the installed MS Office. Most people are on MS Office version 2007-2010. I know that MS provide some sort of interoperability DLLs for this purpose but I haven;t seen any example of this being used with Qt.

Update - this answer looks interesting, can the same be done in Qt?

[Convert Word file pages to jpg images using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326478/convert-word-file-pages-to-jpg-images-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell

It looks like you can do it with Powershell on the commandline pretty easily.

Open a `QProcess`, and run:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

```
powershell -Command "Import-Module MSOnline";"C:\Myscript.ps1"
```

(Download this script or convert it to C++ com calls.)

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Script-to-convert-Word-f702844d

```
powershell -Command "Import-Module ConvertWordPocumentToPDF.psm1";"ConvertTo-OSCPDF -Path C:\path\to\document.docx"
```

So the end code for Qt probably could be something like:

```
QProcess * process = new QProcess();

// put code to pipe stdout and stderr from the QProcess to this exe's stdout, or to a TextEdit.

process->start("powershell.exe -Command \"Import-Module ConvertWordPocumentToPDF.psm1\";\"ConvertTo-OSCPDF -Path C:\\path\\to\\document.docx\"");
```

## Com Object Access

### DocumentBase.ExportAsFixedFormat Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.documentbase.exportasfixedformat.aspx

```
public void ExportAsFixedFormat(
    string outputFileName,
    WdExportFormat exportFormat,
    bool openAfterExport,
    WdExportOptimizeFor optimizeFor,
    WdExportRange range,
    int from,
    int to,
    WdExportItem item,
    bool includeDocProps,
    bool keepIRM,
    WdExportCreateBookmarks createBookmarks,
    bool docStructureTags,
    bool bitmapMissingFonts,
    bool useISO19005_1,
    ref Object fixedFormatExtClassPtr
)
```

First get an instance of a `Word.Application`

then get an instance of a document using `wdApplication.Documents.Open`

then call `wdDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat`, with the parameters of:

```
$wdExportFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat]::wdExportFormatPDF
$OpenAfterExport = $false
$wdExportOptimizeFor = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor]::wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen
$wdExportItem = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem]::wdExportDocumentContent
$IncludeDocProps = $true
$KeepIRM = $true
$wdExportCreateBookmarks = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks]::wdExportCreateWordBookmarks
$DocStructureTags = $true
$BitmapMissingFonts = $true
$UseISO19005_1 = $false
$wdStartPage = 0
$wdEndPage = 0
```

(but formatted for c++, not powershell)

then when it is completed, release the com objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx

I haven't tested either method, but I have ran Com objects from a Qt project before. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I assume powershell is standard with Windows 7 Pro

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Versions  Included in XP SP3 and above, as far as I can tell.