# How to convert word to image files in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, ms-word

I have some doc or docx files.I want to convert them to images automatically if I upload doc files to server.
Does anyone have solutions to solve this problem?
the final target is just like this.
http://www.liuyang.gov.cn/lyswszf/rdzt/15762/content_114176.html
thanks .

Comment: Look here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326478/convert-word-file-pages-to-jpg-images-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a third party component: Aspose.Words, it can do it for you.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Document.doc");

doc.Save(MyDir + "Document.ConvertToHtml Out.html", SaveFormat.Html);
```

it also support save to Png format.

SaveFormat.Png: Renders a page of the document and saves it as a PNG file.