# Convert Word docx file or PDF to Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, bitmap

I try a lot of time to find a way to convert my word file pages or pdf pages to bitmap in high quality. I've tried the packages that I need a license to use them but there is a limitation for the pages. I've also tried with ironPdf but it does not work outside the visual studio because of the license. Is there any package that make it for free and well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21826282/2073738

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Word file pages to jpg images using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326478/convert-word-file-pages-to-jpg-images-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've tried this. Because the spaces between the words in my file are not equal (align text to both the left and right margins), the solution with the bits does not recognize it and the output image is not precise.